# Subclass constructor with different values

Tags: java, constructor

I have parent class Hammer and then his child class Mjolnir. I want to set the remainingUsage for Mjolnir to 4. I managed to do it by creating method in Hammer classs called setUsage and then use it in Mjolnir constructor. Is it possible to do it in more easy way without that setUsage method?

```
public class Hammer extends AbstractActor {
private int remainingUsage;
private Animation image;

public Hammer() {
    this.remainingUsage = 1;
    image = new Animation("sprites/hammer.png");
    setAnimation(image);
}
}
public class Mjolnir extends Hammer {
    Mjolnir(){
        super();
        this.setUsage(4);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can modify the constructor of `Hammer` and pass the remaining usage when creating the object. Like `public Hammer(int rUsage) { ... this.remainingUsage = rUsage;` and then when calling `super(4);`, or whatever value you want. You can also pass this value to your Mjolnir the same way and pass it down to `Hammer`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

...

```
private remainingUsages;

public Hammer() { this(1); }
public Hammer(int remainingUsages) { this.remainingUsages = remainingUsages; }
```

And then just call `super(4)` from your subclass. Calling other methods within your constructor is not good practice.